# Difference between code signing certificate and document signing certificate

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf, digital-certificate

I am looking at getting a document signing certificate to sign PDFs as per Adobe's AATL however I noticed, for example that Digicert charge significantly different prices for a [Document Signing Certificate](https://www.digicert.com/document-signing/) than a [Code Signing Certificate](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/code-signing.htm). We plan to use the certificate to do automated signing of PDFs so I can't see the USB token (offered by the Document signing certificate) being that useful. Considering both certificate/private key pair as signed by the same CA: Digicert, and are on the AATL (and therefore their root cert be the same?) would using a code signing certificate be suffice to validate on Adobe readers?

Customer support at Digicert say:

> if you're using the certificate through your own software then a code
>   signing certificate may work since it chains back to the trusted
>   DigiCert root. I can't confirm whether or not the code signing
>   signature will translate to a PDF however since we don't officially
>   support PDF signing with a code signing certificate.

If anyone has experience with this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It will work but don't forget that this certificate thing is all based in trust. The question is if the validator trusts the the top certificate in a code signing certificate when it expects something else.

Comment: did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely those code signing certificates have an `extKeyUsage (2 5 29 37)` extension with value `codeSigning (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 3 3)` and probably also `commercialCodeSigning (1 3 6 1 4 1 311 2 1 22)` but no values allowing other uses. (At least that is the case for a code signing certificate I have at hands here.)

[RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12) specifies for the Extended Key Usage extension that *if the extension is present, then the certificate MUST only be used for one of the purposes indicated.*

Thus, if the extended key usages in the certificates in question are set as mentioned above, using such a code signing certificate for signing non-code violates the basic specification for X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificates.

So concerning your central question

> We plan to use the certificate to do automated signing of PDFs ... would using a code signing certificate be suffice to validate on Adobe readers?

chances are that Adobe Reader rejects PDF signatures generated using a code signing certificate, and if it doesn't now, it may very well in a future version.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I suspect your analysis is probably correct. I am yet to test your hypothesis, but if I get the chance I will, and report back!

Comment: Ever figure this out?